# Наш язык русский или великорусский?

Tags: этимология

На французском языке говорит француз, на китайском - китаец. Я говорю на русском и считаю себя великороссом. Значит, и язык наш великорусский, а не русский?

Answer (score 1):

Кем вы себя считаете, к делу не относится.

Язык одно время назывался **великоросским** (великорусский - это уже позднейшее), но исключительно в высоком стиле (как его тогда понимали) или при противопоставлении "малоросскому" и "белоросскому" (белорусскому). При этом понятие языка и диалекта еще не было окончательно сформулировано, фактически эти "языки" понимались как диалекты одного, собственно русского языка. Просто слово диалект было еще не в ходу.

С развитием учения о языке и приходом новых реалий названные языки стали восприниматься как полноценные языки, а слово диалект прочно вошло в терминологию. Надобность в использования понятия "великоросский (великорусский) язык" отпала.

Так что вы можете говорить только на великорусском ***диалекте***, противопоставляемом южному (говору или наречию), северному, северо-западному и прочим. Да и то, это понятие за пределами специальной литературы сейчас выходит из употребления.

Ваша самоидентификация вам чести не делает, но она и не имеет отношения к вопросу.